# A user has not as much reputation as upvotes would suggest. Why?

Tags: discussion, reputation, upvotes, daily-reputation-limit

I just found this answer at Stack Overflow and now I'm wondering how this is possible.

[Link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools/21693931#21693931)

As you can see, the user has 1584 upvotes, and with every upvote you get 10 reputation points.
1584 * 10 = 15840. But the user only has 4k reputation.

Looking into his account he also has only six answers on Stack Overflow at all. So the difference can't be because of another question/answer with downvotes.

How is this difference possible? Will you get only a amount of reputation for one answer, and after you've been upvoted too high you won't get it any more?

Comment: Um. Daily reputation caps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot earn more than 200 points from votes and suggested edits in a day. The user hit the reputation cap [several times early on](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630946/alf?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=4):

[image]

You can still earn reputation from bonuses, accepts and the association bonus, which is why they gained 315 on the 11th.

The reputation cap exists to prevent users from gaining privileges and 'trust' too rapidly from a popular answer, among other reasons.

Comment: I did not know there was a a reputation cap. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken:

> with every upvote you get 10 reputation points

No, you don't. Not if you hit the 200 a day reputation cap, after which you no longer gain reputation from upvotes that day.

Reputation is thoroughly documented on [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)